# What assumptions about the file system layout can be made?

Tags: discussion, policy

At times, it may be advantageous for a solution to a challenge to make certain assumptions about, for example, the directory from which it is run. For example, a bash script that compiles and runs a file with `gcc` can reduce

```
./a.out
```

to

```
./a*
```

if it can safely assume that no other files in the present working directory have a name that begins with `a`.

Should this be allowed? What about assumptions about the file name of the code being run? We already have a policy that adds the length of the file name to the score if it has to have a certain name (informal? I can't find a definitive statement of this policy), but what if the file name simply *can't* be a certain string (for example, the bash script above would have to have a name that *doesn't* start with `a`)?

Another interesting conundrum is tricks like `/d*/u*m` instead of `/dev/urandom`. On my system, `/dev/urandom` is the only file that matches the glob, but this may not be the case on others.

How should these cases be handled?

<sup>(note that my self-answers are intended as proposals and not declarations; treat them in the same manner as you would if they were posted by any other user.)</sup>

Answer (score 13):

### Assumptions about the working directory

The present working directory may be assumed to be empty. If the program is run from a file, the present working directory may alternatively be assumed to be empty except for the file being run.

However, nothing may be assumed about the full path to the present working directory except that it is a legal path name on the system in question. (That is, solutions must handle cases where the path to the present working directory contains spaces, for example.)

If a submission requires an extra file in the present working directory, it should be counted according to [our existing policy for multi-file submissions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4933/3808).

Comment: "solutions must handle cases where the path to the present working directory contains spaces" — I'm not sure about this requirement, and I think there are several existing answers where this isn't the case (first example I found via Google is https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104930/8927). In the same vein as basic ASCII being an acceptable assumption for text entry (i.e. unicode not required by default), I'd say `[a-zA-Z0-9_/]+` is an acceptable assumption for file paths, unless otherwise stated.

Comment: Must programs assume a case sensitive or non case sensitive file system, or should they work on both

Answer (score 11):

### Assumptions about the file name

To restate a policy that I thought we had but can't actually find a source for: If the submission is required to have a certain file name, the length of the file name must be added to the submission's score.

If the submission fails for *any* legal file name, it *must* specify a file name to be used and count this name in the score. (This does not apply to submissions that can be run by providing the code itself as a command line argument, of course.) This is the only way I can think of to prevent abuse of the rules such as "this works for an infinite number of file names, but it has to start with `Hello, World!`."

To put it another way, a file name (this applies for every file name in multi-file submissions) can only not be counted in the score when the file name is wholly immaterial to the functionality of the submission and only affects the invocation of the submission. This is consistent with [our existing policy for multi-file submissions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4933/3808).

Comment: The only "problem" I can think of is a unicode file name, since it's legal (at least on windows), but there are languages that don't have unicode support.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Can you give an example for a language that has problems with unicode filenames (with an otherwise normal source like Hello World)?

Comment: @L3viathan [C in my own terminal](https://pastebin.com/raw/J7D7HBZw), but it [works fine on TIO](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BPTcxM09Ds1qhoLSkWEPJIzUnJ19HITy/KCdFUUnTWqFWXcFO4cGmBfFArJfMlZ6cjOAp6ObDOFx6@lDW//8A). Largely, anything written in a language without unicode support

Comment: @ConorO'Brien I don't think that "ASCII-only filename" is a restriction that would run afoul of this rule. You're not storing information in the filename - you're just dealing with a restriction of the language. Similarly, if restrictions are imposed by the language and not the specific program (like requiring a certain file extension), that shouldn't be counted against the program.

Comment: @Mego I think that's perfect. I wasn't sure to what extent "legal" meant.

Answer (score 0):

## Quinelike things can't store info in the file name

you may not print(filename) etc.

Comment: IMO this is covered by [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1789/45941) and [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1072/45941)

Comment: just covering up doorknobs answer about file name

Comment: I don't think this answer is relevant